# Given a divergent series $\sum x_n$ with $x_{n} \rightarrow 0$, show there exists a divergent series $\sum y_{n} $ with $ y_n/x_n\rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

The problem is what the title says, with the added requrement that both series should have positive terms.

I ruled out defining $y_{n}$ by $x_{n}$ divided by some function of $n$ since I can't see how we can guarantee it's sum is divergent.

So instead I was looking at defining $y_{n} = max \{ x_{2^{n}} , x_{2^{n}+1} , ... , \} $ but even if this were to work, I have no idea how to prove it.

**So can a simple/general $y_{n}$ be found that satisfies these conditions?**

Comment: Is this your question: "Suppose $\left(x_n\right)$ is a sequence with $x_n \to 0$ and $\sum x_n$ divergent.  Show there exists a sequence $(y_n)$ such that $\frac{y_n}{x_n} \to 0$ but $\sum y_n$ is divergent"?

Comment: @Masacroso But then $ y_{n} / x_{n} = n $ which doesn't tend to 0 as n tends to infinity.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes.

Comment: OK, I think you need to reword the question (by the way, notation like $\exists$ and "s.t." are good for note-taking and scratch work, but are less readable than english words).

Comment: I dont think that a simple rule exists, but you can prove that such sequence exists (I dont remember now how but is possible). Start with the definitions of divergent series.

Comment: @EvgenyT is $x_n$ positive ?

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM yes, sorry it is.

Comment: This problem needs restating. It should have the form "let $x_n$ be a sequence with property P. Show there is a sequence $y_n$ with property Q."

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM Just let $S_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n \lvert x_k\rvert$ and $y_k = \lvert x_k\rvert/S_k$. $x_n > 0$ only saves typing.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming $x_n>0$ for all $n$, let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k$.

Since $\sum_n x_n$ diverges, $S_n$ is increasing and diverges to $\infty$, hence $\displaystyle \frac{x_n}{S_n} = o(x_n)$

It is the case that $\displaystyle \sum_n \frac{x_n}{S_n}$ diverges.

This follows swiftly from Cauchy criterion: for any $N\geq 1$ and $p\geq 1$, $$\sum_{k=N+1}^{N+p}\frac{x_k}{S_k}\geq \frac{1}{S_{N+p}} \sum_{k=N+1}^{N+p}x_k = 1-\frac{S_{N}}{S_{N+p}}{\longrightarrow}_{p\to \infty} 1$$

Given $N\geq 1$, you can therefore find some $p\geq 1$ such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=N+1}^{N+p}\frac{x_k}{S_k}\geq \frac 12$, hence divergence.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more general result: If $\sum x_n$ is a positive divergent series, then there exists a positive divergent series $\sum y_n$ such that $y_n/x_n \to 0.$ (Note that if in addition we have $x_n$ bounded, then $y_n \to 0.$)

Proof: There are integers $1=n_1 < n_2 < \cdots \to \infty$ such that

$$\sum_{n=n_k}^{n_{k+1}-1} x_n > 1$$

for all $k.$ Let $B_k = \{n: n_k \le n < n_{k+1}\}.$ Define the sequence $y_n$ block by block: If $n\in B_k,$ set $y_n = x_n/k.$ Then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n\in B_k}\frac{x_n}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\sum_{n\in B_k}x_n \ge \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}\cdot 1 = \infty.$$

For $n\in B_k$ we have $y_n/x_n = 1/k.$ As $n\to \infty,$ $n$ moves through all blocks $B_1, B_2, \dots$ forcing $y_n/x_n \to 0.$